# debugging GDB Interrupt when no error is shown

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios

I'm having a problem where I'm receiving a GDB Interrupt at a particular point while running my app in debug but no error message is being displayed in the debugger.

The code in question is:

```
- (void)AddContactViewControllerDidFinish:(AddContactViewController *)controller {
 // Save contact & requirement
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
 Contact *contactObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:context];

 [contactObj setValue:[[[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0] text] forKey:@"Name"];
 [contactObj setValue:[[[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1] text] forKey:@"PhoneBH"];
 [contactObj setValue:[[[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:2] text] forKey:@"PhoneAH"];
 [contactObj setValue:[[[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:3] text] forKey:@"Mobile"];
 [contactObj setValue:[[[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:4] text] forKey:@"Email"];
 UISwitch *switcho = [[controller.textFields objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:5];
 [contactObj setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:switcho.on] forKey:@"PropertyAlerts"];
 NSDate *LastModified = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 [contactObj setValue:LastModified forKey:@"LastModified"];
 [LastModified release];
 [openhome addContactObject:contactObj];
 [contactObj addOpenhomeObject:openhome];
```

The last line here is where I am receiving the interrupt. Essentially what I'm doing here is preparing the contactObj for saving using Core Data and this delegate method is called when a Done button is hit within a view controller displayed in a modal.

So my question is, as there is no error displayed **how do I go about finding what is causing the interrupt?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with instruments and NSZombie enabled. Sometimes XCode acts weird and just stops the execution without showing an error, but instruments should be more verbose.